# sqlite3_exec without callback

Tags: sqlite, callback

Is there any way by which I can get the sqlite3_exec() result without through callback?
When I do search I want to get the result directly, most like a return of the function or as OUT param?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I have written some code that allows us to read data from open db (db) according to sql query (zSql) without callback.
Please note, that this code works but might still need some work (for example, I'm not sure if we need to free the text data or not...)

```
int RunSqlNoCallback(sqlite3 * db, const char * zSql)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, zSql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        return rc;

    int rowCount = 0;
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    while (rc != SQLITE_DONE && rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        rowCount++;
        int colCount = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
        {
            int type = sqlite3_column_type(stmt, colIndex);
            const char * columnName = sqlite3_column_name(stmt, colIndex);
            if (type == SQLITE_INTEGER)
            {
                int valInt = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, colIndex);
                printf("columnName = %s, Integer val = %d", columnName, valInt);
            }
            else if (type == SQLITE_FLOAT)
            {
                double valDouble = sqlite3_column_double(stmt, colIndex);
                printf("columnName = %s,Double val = %f", columnName, valDouble);
            }
            else if (type == SQLITE_TEXT)
            {
                const unsigned char * valChar = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, colIndex);
                printf("columnName = %s,Text val = %s", columnName, valChar);
                free(valChar);
            }
            else if (type == SQLITE_BLOB)
            {
                printf("columnName = %s,BLOB", columnName);
            }
            else if (type == SQLITE_NULL)
            {
                printf("columnName = %s,NULL", columnName);
            }
        }
        printf("Line %d, rowCount = %d", rowCount, colCount);

        rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    }

    rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This code is working well for me.  Although, I don't think we should be freeing the valChar.  For one thing: it crashes for me after some iteration, and I think it's a pointer to static content within the database, not a copy of it.

Comment: It says here: https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_column_blob that the memory is free'd automatically: " The memory space used to hold strings and BLOBs is freed automatically. Do not pass the pointers returned from sqlite3_column_blob(), sqlite3_column_text(), etc. into sqlite3_free()."

Answer (score 2):

`sqlite3_exec` is a convenience wrapper.

If you don't need a callback you should use underlying functions: `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`, `sqlite3_step()`, and `sqlite3_finalize()` directly.

1. Compile sql query with `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`
2. Run `sqlite3_step()` as many times as necessary to execute the query, use 
    `sqlite3_column_bytes()` etc to retrieve the data
3. Destroy prepared query with `sqlite3_finalize()`

But it requires more coding and careful error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the callback is how `sqlite3_exec` is designed to work.

If you want a function that allocates all the memory for the result and returns that, you need a different function, like [`sqlite3_get_table`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/free_table.html).

Comment: It looks like that sqlite3_get_table() is not recommended for use and is a legacy kept for compatibility http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/free_table.html

Answer (score 0):

The call back is the mechanism that `sqlite3_exec ()` uses to return one or more results.  It looks like its primary use is with a select SQL statement.  If the select SQL statement returns multiple rows of results then the call back function specified is called by the sqlite functionality for each row.

I am not sure if you are using C or C++ or some other language however I have a possible solution for you using C with SQLite.

The call back function has as its first argument a void pointer and this can point to pretty much anything.  For instance it can point to a struct that contains a pointer to a memory area allocated for the result along with parameters indicating the size of the memory area.

I put an answer to this stackoverflow question, [use of sql3_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805982/use-of-sqlite3-exec/16964389), with an example of using a call back that populates a C struct with the results of a select SQL statement.  In this example I have a call back that takes one or more row results from a select and transform the results into the data values to put into a C struct.  When the `sqlite3_exec()` function returns, I then process the results from the select using the C struct.

This may be what you are looking for in that you can create your select SQL statement, set up the results struct, call `sqlite3_exec()` specifying the results struct along with the function pointer to the call back to process the results using the results struct, and when `sqlite3_exec()` return you have the results of your select.  The results of the select will be at the point where you called `sqlite3_exec()`.

Comment: Certain answers on here are troublesome. You told the original questioner how to do something it's clear he knows how to do already and it's a method he's trying to avoid.