# Error when Updating SQLite in XCODE

Tags: xcode, sqlite

I am trying to UPDATE a row in a sqlite table, but I am getting an error when I do the exec command. 
I have a method within a DBManager Class that attempts to update the table.

```
-(void) UpdateContactsTable :(NSString *) tableName
                        withField1:(NSString *) field1
                       field1Value:(NSString *) field1Value
                         andField2:(NSString *) field2
                       field2Value:(NSString *) field2Value
                         andField3:(NSString *) field3
                       field3Value:(NSString *) field3Value
                         andField4:(NSString *) field4
                       field4Value:(NSString *) field4Value
                         andField5:(NSString *) field5
                       field5Value:(NSString *) field5Value
                         andField6:(NSString *) field6
                       field6Value:(NSNumber *) field6Value

{

[self openDB];
sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE CONTACTS SET NAME = ?, SURNAME1 = ?, SURNAME2 = ?, PHONE = ?, EMAIL = ?, PID = ? WHERE PID = '%i'", [field6Value integerValue]];
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String] , -1,
                       &updateStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [field1Value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 2, [field2Value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 3, [field3Value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 4, [field4Value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 5, [field5Value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
}

char* errmsg;
NSLog(@"sqlite commit %d",sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errmsg));
sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt)){
    NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

The lines:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [field1Value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Return a value of 0, so I guess they are correct.

Where I get the error message is in the:

```
sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
```

Where I get a returned value of 20. And the:

```
if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt)){
NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
```

Returns a value of 21. And the table does not get updated.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the [sqlite3_exec documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html). Anmd are you aware that the SQL command has six parameters?

Comment: Thanks @CL, I think you will find it says it needs 5 parameters. Yes, I have read the documentation and followed several examples, but it still gives me the error.

Comment: I said "the first paragraph". And I count six `?` characters.

Comment: Hi @CL, I still count 5:sqlite3*,                                  /* An open database */
  const char *sql,                           /* SQL to be evaluated */
  int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
  void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
  char **errmsg                              /* Error msg written here */

Comment: [Parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam)

Comment: @CL would you kindly spell out the 6 parameters you are talking about so that I can resolve the issue, rather than have an accounting conversation? Thanks

Comment: @CL, please refer to this example of sqlite_exec() where there are % - FIVE - parameters: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805982/use-of-sqlite3-exec). Furthermore the sqlite documentation does not mention a 6th parameter, but it says:  then sqlite3_exec() sets the pointer in its 5th parameter to NULL before returning. I think you will find that the BEFORE RETURNING is kind of obvious.

Comment: The six parameters are `?`, `?`, `?`, `?`, `?`, and `?`. You set only five. And `sqlite3_exec()` already calls `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`, `sqlite3_step()`, and `sqlite3_finalize()`, so you have two independent statements, one of which doesn't have set any of its parameters at all.

Comment: Ah!!!! You are talking about the 6 parameters I am passing into the method, NOT the sqlite3_exce parameters!! OK, so I am missing a bind statement!! Yes, put that in, for the last field and it works. Got there in the end! Thanks.