# How to know if function 'callback' in sqlite returned something?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

For example my inquiry(question?) in SQL is:

```
 SELECT * from COMPANY where imie="John",surname="Wattson",age=31;
```

I use `sqlite3_exec` where one of the arguments is `callback`. I don't know if this record is in my table, and would like to know it using `sqlite_exec`.

What should I do?
Sorry for my English. :(

Comment: Have you supplied a valid callback pointer to `sqlite3_exec()`?

Comment: probably not, don't know how to do this

Comment: Forgive me, but what does "probably not" mean? Have you written any code?

Comment: I have written but didn't use any pointer, so suspect it's not correct

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805982/use-of-sqlite3-exec) on how to use `sqlite3_exec()`

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with me but i can't find an answer. I can't understand it and it's too much information for me :/

Comment: If you are not familiar with using function pointers in C++, you should really tackle that problem first. Then this question will answer itself.

Comment: I'm familiar, but still don't know how should i do this. Do you have any example of using it? At your answer maybe it is but I can't find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to see if a record exists in the table, then you could do it with `sqlite3_exec()` using a callback function like this:

```
int myCallback(void *pUser, int argc, char **colData, char **colNames) {
  int *flag = (int*)pUser;
  *flag = 1;
  return 1;
}
```

This works because if there are no records matching the query, then the callback function is not called. By returning 1 instead of 0, we are telling SQLite that we don't want any more rows from the query results.

Then, in the function where you are making the db query:

```
std::string sql = "SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE imie='John' AND surname='Wattson' AND age=31;";
char *pSql = sql.c_str(); // char*'s are better for talking to SQLite, and prior to C++14,
                          // a std::string is not guaranteed to be sequential in memory,
                          // so 'sql[0]' may not work right

char *pError = NULL;
int fHasResult = 0;

// db is an already-opened sqlite3*
int result = sqlite3_exec(db, pSql, myCallback, &fHasResult, &pError);
if (result) {
  cout<<"Error was: "<<pError;
  free(pError);
}
if (fHasResult) {
  cout<<"The row exists in the database.";
}
else {
  cout<<"The row does not exist in the database.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `EXISTS`, your query should then look something like this;
`SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE imie="John" AND surname="Wattson" AND age=31);`
For another example you could take a look at this;
[Valid query to check if row exists in SQLite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755860/valid-query-to-check-if-row-exists-in-sqlite3)

Comment: Thanks it's helpful, but now how get this value to the variable?

Comment: Oh, you're using c++, so I probably won't be of any help, but the best suggestion I can give you is to fetch the first row in the resultset, which will then contain the result, although I do not know how you could implement that in c++. (Good luck!)